# Execute chartjs after an ajax call with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, chart.js

I want to load the ChartJs Chart after an ajax call. But unfortunately, it showing Undefined variable errors for all ChartJS php variables.

**Target:**

Change the chart based on user select from the dropdown list, each selection option is basically a JSON link from where we fetch the data to show with chartjs.

**What I have done so far:**

- Setup an AJAX call which works ok for each user select both "default"
  on page  load plus "on change" options.
- Added Chartjs code after the successful ajax request section.
- Tested all JSON codes & php data its all working ok.
- All ajax return data for chartjs php variables are ok.

**Issues:**

- Undefined variable error for all chartjs PHP variables (name,
  cot_labels,
  cot_values,cot_values2,cot_values3,cot_values4,cot_values5)
- No data showing on chart.
- Chart also not refreshing with new data when user select another option.

Here is the Javascript part:

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
                  $.ajax({
          url: "./url.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            cur: $("#cur").val()
          },
           success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                        new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [<?php echo '"'.$cot_labels.'"'; ?>],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values; ?>],
        label: "A",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values2; ?>],
        label: "B",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      } ,
      { 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values3; ?>],
        label: "C",
        borderColor: "#085b83",
        fill: false
      }  ,
      { 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values4; ?>],
        label: "D",
        borderColor: "#1c2925",
        fill: false
      } ,
        { 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values5; ?>],
        label: "E",
        borderColor: "#b9801d",
        fill: false
      } 
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: '<?php echo $name; ?>'
    },
     animation: {
            duration: 0, // general animation time
        },
         hover: {
            animationDuration: 0, // duration of animations when hovering an item
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0, // animation duration after a resize
  }
}); 
                }         
             });
    $('#cur').on('change', function() {
          $.ajax({
          url: "./url.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            cur: $("#cur").val()
          },
           success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                        new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [<?php echo '"'.$cot_labels.'"'; ?>],
    datasets: [{ 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values; ?>],
        label: "A",
        borderColor: "#3e95cd",
        fill: false
      }, { 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values2; ?>],
        label: "B",
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false
      } ,
      { 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values3; ?>],
        label: "C",
        borderColor: "#085b83",
        fill: false
      }  ,
      { 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values4; ?>],
        label: "D",
        borderColor: "#1c2925",
        fill: false
      } ,
        { 
        data: [<?php echo $cot_values5; ?>],
        label: "E",
        borderColor: "#b9801d",
        fill: false
      } 
    ]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: '<?php echo $name; ?>'
    },
     animation: {
            duration: 0, // general animation time
        },
         hover: {
            animationDuration: 0, // duration of animations when hovering an item
        },
        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0, // animation duration after a resize
  }
}); 
                }
          
             });
       });
       });
```

```html
           <select id="cur" name="cur">
    <option value="<?php echo $euro;?>">EURO</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $pound;?>">UK</option>
   
</select>
        <canvas id="line-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
```

Here is the PHP Part:

```
 $euro = "URL";
    $pound = "URL";

//AJAX CALL
 if (isset($_POST['cur'])) {
   $cur = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cur', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
          //Build arrays
 $cot_label_arr = array();
 $cot_value_arr = array();
 $cot_value_arr2 = array();
 $cot_value_arr3 = array();
 $cot_value_arr4 = array();
 $cot_value_arr5 = array();
   $json=file_get_contents($cur);
 $data =  json_decode($json);
  foreach ($data as $item  ) {
  $name = $item->name;
 // echo $item->newest_available_date;
  foreach($item as $value => $value_1){
    if (is_array($value_1) || is_object($value_1))
   {
    foreach($value_1  as $value_2 ){                 
         if (is_array($value_2) || is_object($value_2))
    {
             $cot_label_arr[] = date('M j Y',strtotime($value_2[0])); //pull dates
             $cot_value_arr[] = $value_2[1]; 
             $cot_value_arr2[] = $value_2[2]; 
             $cot_value_arr3[] = $value_2[3]; 
             $cot_value_arr4[] = $value_2[4]; 
             $cot_value_arr5[] = $value_2[5];                

        }
       }

     }
   }
  }
$cot_labels = array_reverse($cot_label_arr); //reverse the data for ASC
$cot_values = array_reverse($cot_value_arr); //reverse the data for ASC
$cot_values2 = array_reverse($cot_value_arr2); //reverse the data for ASC
$cot_values3 = array_reverse($cot_value_arr3); //reverse the data for ASC
$cot_values4 = array_reverse($cot_value_arr4); //reverse the data for ASC
$cot_values5 = array_reverse($cot_value_arr5); //reverse the data for ASC
//----
$cot_labels = implode('","', $cot_labels); //comma sep
$cot_values = implode(", ", $cot_values); //comma sep
$cot_values2 = implode(", ", $cot_values2); //comma sep
$cot_values3 = implode(", ", $cot_values3); //comma sep
$cot_values4 = implode(", ", $cot_values4); //comma sep
$cot_values5 = implode(", ", $cot_values5); //comma sep
 exit;
 } // End of ajax call
```

If I use `echo $cot_values;` inside the ajax call, then I get to see correct data. But chartjs is not loading with it. Here is the screenshot of what I get returned for $cot_values.

[image]

Not sure why I am getting undefined data error for chartjs php variables whereas I am calling the chartjs javascript after the successful ajax call. Plus why the correct data is not loading on the chart.

**UPDATE: with  MLStud coding**

Now no longer undefined php chartjs variable error as we are using java json data. But the chart is not loading, in the place of the chart a white blank space is showing. I have tested all data for any kind of wrong format, but it was ok.

Here is the updated coding part:

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['cur'])) {     
........
$cot_labels = implode(", ", $cot_labels); //edited as it was showing date with extra ""
$cot_values = implode(", ", $cot_values); //comma sep
$cot_values2 = implode(", ", $cot_values2); //comma sep
$cot_values3 = implode(", ", $cot_values3); //comma sep
$cot_values4 = implode(", ", $cot_values4); //comma sep
$cot_values5 = implode(", ", $cot_values5); //comma sep

 // New added
 $result = array(
'cot_labels'=>$cot_labels,
'cot_values'=>$cot_values,
'cot_values2'=>$cot_values2,
'cot_values3'=>$cot_values3,
'cot_values4'=>$cot_values4,
'cot_values5'=>$cot_values5,
'name'=>$name

   );
  print_r(json_encode($result));
   exit;
   } // End of ajax call
```

**Javascript + HTML :**

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
                  $.ajax({
          url: "./url.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            cur: $("#cur").val()
          },
           success: function(data) {   
             alert(data);
             var datos = JSON.parse(data);       
                 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: datos.cot_labels, ///in this way you access the data of the returned json
                        datasets: [{
                            data: datos.cot_values,///in this way you access the data of the returned json
                            label: "A",
                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                            fill: false
                        }, {
                            data: datos.cot_values2,
                            label: "B",
                            borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: data.name
                        },
                        animation: {
                            duration: 0, // general animation time
                        },
                        hover: {
                            animationDuration: 0, // duration of animations when hovering an item
                        },
                        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0, // animation duration after a resize
                    }
                }); 
                }         
             });
    $('#cur').on('change', function() {    
          $.ajax({
          url: "./url.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            cur: $("#cur").val()
          },
           success: function(data) {         
               var datos = JSON.parse(data);  
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: datos.cot_labels, ///in this way you access the data of the returned json
                        datasets: [{
                            data: datos.cot_values,///in this way you access the data of the returned json
                            label: "A",
                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                            fill: false
                        }, {
                            data: datos.cot_values2,
                            label: "B",
                            borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: data.name
                        },
                        animation: {
                            duration: 0, // general animation time
                        },
                        hover: {
                            animationDuration: 0, // duration of animations when hovering an item
                        },
                        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0, // animation duration after a resize
                    }
                });
                }
          
             });
       });
       });
```

```html
  <select id="cur" name="cur">
    <option value="<?php echo $euro;?>">EURO</option>
    <option value="<?php echo $pound;?>">UK</option>
   
</select>
 <canvas id="myChart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
```

For more further verification here is the date format how it looks like: (when we call it after successful ajax call)

```
       alert(datos.cot_labels);
```

[image]

Comment: Just a detail, in Ajax JavaScript part **url: "./url"**, should be: **url: "./url.php"**

Comment: Edited, still same issues.

Comment: Please remove the php code in the js file and replace those by the letters what the browser has received.

Comment: Pardon, not sure what you meant, one example could help. Do you want me to replace $cot_values into what?

Comment: From page view source I got data as `data: []`

Comment: @mimi What I meant: replace `labels: [<?php echo '"'.$cot_labels.'"'; ?>]`by `labels: [here put in stuff from browser],`

Comment: @reporter $col_labels are dates & it get changed by user selection. Lots of dates in such format "2018-04-08".....The chart was working ok before the ajax implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To take the value of variables you have to access the json obtained as an answer (data) and you have to convert "val1, val2, ..." in the vector [val1, val2, ...] with [split](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
        $.ajax({
            url: "server.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                ...
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var datos = JSON.parse(data);
                var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
                        labels: datos.cot_labels.split(','), ///in this way you access the data of the returned json
                        datasets: [{
                            data: datos.cot_values.split(','),///in this way you access the data of the returned json
                            label: "A",
                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                            fill: false
                        }, {
                            data: datos.cot_values2.split(','),
                            label: "B",
                            borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
                            fill: false
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: datos.name
                        },
                        animation: {
                            duration: 0, // general animation time
                        },
                        hover: {
                            animationDuration: 0, // duration of animations when hovering an item
                        },
                        responsiveAnimationDuration: 0, // animation duration after a resize
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Result:

[image: Chart Line 1]

[image: Chart Line 2]

Comment: I have added the result array part inside the ajax call last section. Then I have added the `data={"cot_labels":null,"cot_values":valorcot_values,"cot_values2":valorcot_values2,"cot_values3":valorcot_values3,"cot_values4":valorcot_values4,"cot_values5":valorcot_values5};` part above the ` new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart")` the start of the charjs code. But still same errors showing up, no chart its displaying. Previously it used to display at least the chart, but no data on it. Now no chart.

Comment: The json that I put is just one example of what the ajax call should return in the data variable. To load the data you need charts you must access that data

Comment: when ajax returns data okay with my previous coding. Then why does a separate array required? Updated my question with a picture.

Comment: plus inside the chartjs coding, how should I call those json data for level & data. for example I have currently this `labels: [<?php echo '"'.$cot_labels.'"'; ?>]`  what I should write for it with your coding? could you please provide an example of chartjs coding.

Comment: Edit my answer with an example. Greetings.

Comment: Thank you so much for adding the coding part in detail with example. I will test it tomorrow & let you know. :)

Comment: I am testing it, may I know which version of chartjs you have used for the coding example? I was here using latest version 2.7.2. So I need to change it to your version.

Comment: I used version 2.7.2 and included it from: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js

Comment: Hello, I have edited the code based on your coding. Now no php undefine variable error. But chart is not loading, only showing a blank white space. here is the jsfiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/cashcube/f0up139o/ I have tested the data individually, its showing ok with `alert(datos.cot_values)`

Comment: You can eliminate this question and make another one where you explain what your new problem is. You must put all the necessary code and error messages obtained.

Comment: I can not create any more new question(limit), plus this problem is relevant to this question. As I have used your coding example. If you want then I can update my question with your codes.

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Comment: In the <head> tag of your html you have to include: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>

Comment: Can you put that error message on the navigator's console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169047/discussion-between-mimi-and-mlstud).

Comment: Hello, Updated the discussion could please take a look.